# Best way output entered both command and output of command to stdout/pastebin?

Tags: stdout, output

Let's say I run `inxi -C` and want to output both `inxi -C` and the result of that command (CPU information) to pastebin. How do I do this in the most efficient way?

Comment: Copy paste isn't a valuable solution ?

Comment: Sometimes that's not fast enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why, you can do that with the handy new [`forexample`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/forexample) program ([docs](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/forexample.1), [unit tests](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/misc/t/forexample.t)) assuming the command to be run is something `spawn` can handle; otherwise, you'd need to write this tool directly in the shell itself.

```
$ CLIPBOARD=cat forexample echo hi
    $ echo hi
    hi
    $ 
$
```

By default `CLIPBOARD` is `pbcopy` so either change the code or once `forexample` is properly setup in `PATH` (and `expect` installed) try something like

```
CLIPBOARD='xclip -in' forexample inxi -C
```

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for. How do I install this?

Comment: It's a TCL script so install the `expect` package and then `chmod +x` this script and stash it somewhere in `$PATH`.

Comment: Am I missing something here? `tung@tung-Lenovo-Y50-70 ~ $ gather cat gather
couldn't execute "pbcopy": no such file or directory
    while executing
"open "| pbcopy" w"
    invoked from within
"set clippyfh [open "| pbcopy" w]"
    (file "/usr/bin/gather" line 16)`

Comment: @BananaLeafCat that line has a comment right above it saying `FIXME` as copy-paste programs are unportable...

Comment: I think i have xclip but I don't know how to fix it accordingly... Could you give me an example?